# Converting MHT to PPTX in Python

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx, mhtml

Is there a quick script/code in python to convert MHT/MHTML to PPTX? I have tried searching StackOverflow and google for it. It would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is MHT? If we knew what it was we might be able to suggest something.

Comment: At one time, PPT could save as HTML/MHT in their own sort of proprietary versions of the formats that they could also read back in. As John Korchok's mentioned, that feature's been deprecated for quite some time now. In general, before looking for a way to automate something in PPT, start by figuring out how to do it manually. If it can't be done (for example, if PPT doesn't offer MHT as one of the file types it'll open/import) chances are that you can't do it under program control.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of a python script that can do this. PowerPoint deprecated the MHT filter after Office 2010. You can use an on-line convertor to convert your files: [Free Online MHT to PPT Converter](https://products.groupdocs.app/conversion/mht-to-ppt)

If you have access to Office 2007 or earlier versions, you can use steps similar to those described on this page: [How to Convert a MHT Extension to PowerPoint](https://itstillworks.com/convert-vsd-files-visio-xml-8781870.html). If you have access to Office 2010, a conversion is still possible using VBA.

Comment: Due to DPL I can't use online converters. Python was preferred, but if there is another language that can do this, I would be open to it. Thank you!